# ASP.NET MVC : why is my model blank except for the partial views?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, post

I have a model similar to one shown here. The `Attachment` model is rendered as a partial view, and when an attachment is added, the document is uploaded and there is a call to a `UploadAttachment` method that refreshes the section within the form.

```
public class FormModel
{
    public int DocumentNumber { get; set; }
    public List<Attachment> Attachments { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}

public class Attachment
{
    public int id { get; set;}
}
```

I'm not sure if this was ever working but apparently, when a form is edited and submitted (no attachment is uploaded), the model hits the POST Edit method fine. When the form is edited and an `Attachment` is added at the same time, the model object has all fields as null EXCEPT for the `Attachment` list which makes me think that maybe the submit button on the `FormModel` is getting confused or maybe something happening within the Partial View.

How can I debug this further? Is there a way to see why my model is blank before the POST Edit? I am not great with ASP.NET MVC and debugging has always been an issue for me. Also, don't think it is a naming thing as other blank model questions I've seen on here since the POST Edit does get the form data if no attachment is added.

I have tried to debug this using Javascript to try to view the object on the Submit button click. Is there some Javascript I can do to try and view the model on button click to try to debug to see the model before and after an attachment to see where it is failing?